# ackermann_vehicle_description does not contain the URDF file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I distributed the `ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle`, `ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-description`, and `ros-indigo-ackermann-vehicle-gazebo` Ubuntu packages months ago. It's been brought to my attention that when these packages are installed, most of their files are missing. For example, `/opt/ros/indigo/share/ackermann_vehicle_description` contains only `package.xml` and a `cmake` directory. I think that distribution of `ackermann_vehicle` as Ubuntu packages used to work. Here is a link to my `ackermann_vehicle` and `ackermann_vehicle-release` Git repositories: https://github.com/wunderkammer-laboratory?tab=repositories. I'd appreciate it if someone could let me know why correct Ubuntu packages are not being built.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214693/ackermann_vehicle_description-does-not-contain-the-urdf-file/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/wunderkammer-laboratory/ackermann_vehicle/blob/daf117f9674e22e554a1ddd49beaef31ce68f551/ackermann_vehicle_description/CMakeLists.txt) of `ackerman_vehicle_description`, there seem to be no `install(..)` rules. Without those, no files will be, well, *installed*.

For `ackerman_vehicle_description`, something like:

```
install(DIRECTORY launch urdf
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

should do.

See [catkin 0.6.14 documentation » How to do common tasks » Building and installing targets](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) for more information (and examples) of how to do this.

> I think that distribution of ackermann_vehicle as Ubuntu packages used to work

Looking at the [history](https://github.com/wunderkammer-laboratory/ackermann_vehicle/commits/master/ackermann_vehicle_description/CMakeLists.txt) of the `CMakeLists.txt` in `ackerman_vehicle_description` that seems unlikely, as there has only ever been one version of that file, and it never contained the required `install(..)` statements.

---

Edit: I'd also suggest adding the `architecture_independent` tag to the `export` section of your `package.xml`, as `ackerman_vehicle_description` does not contain any artefacts that will need to be rebuild for different processor architectures (ie: x86 vs x64, etc). That saves the buildfarm some effort, and results in your packages becoming available sooner. Just add the following to the end of your manifest:

```
<export>
  <architecture_independent />
</export>
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2015-08-05**:\

> Looking at the history of the CMakeLists.txt in ackerman_vehicle_description that seems unlikely

I think what has been happening is that users have been forking the Github repository, so I've never noticed the CMakeLists.txt problem.

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2015-08-05**:\

> I'd also suggest adding the architecture_independent tag to the export

Only the metapackage package.xml doesn't have such a tag. I didn't think it was intended for metapackages, but http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#id29 says otherwise. I'll add the tag.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-08-05**:\

> Only the metapackage package.xml doesn't have such a tag.

I think I looked at the repository at the time of the last commit to `CMakeLists.txt`. There it doesn't have an `export` section. But you're right, it is there now.